# Nested if statement in one line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

Right now I have the following line:

```
<div class="<%#  productName.Url.Length > 3 ? "Classic": "" %>">..</div>
```

But the problem is that productName can be null So I am recieving following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

So I need to make sure that this if statement is only executed if productName is not null.

Like this:

```
    if (productName.Url != null)
    {
        if (productName.Url.Length > 3)
        {
            "Classic"
        }
        else
        {
            ""
        }
    }
```

Is the only solution to use one line? Or is there any better solutions?

Comment: So you need to make sure it is `not null` **and** the `length > 3`. Note that putting them on one line will make your `else` ugly.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If its not null then I want it to check the length > 3

Comment: I know, that's what I said. Read it very carefully.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yeah, sorry. How can make the else not getting ugly?

Comment: By splitting them over multiple statements instead of cramming it together (although if the usage is just the one line at the top, then it is okay).

Comment: When you find yourself considering doing this much logic in markup it's a sign that it's time to move the code to the code behind.  You should be doing this logic in the code behind *before* you bind the data, not after, or at the very very least, creating a method in your code behind to handle the transformation so that the markup is only calling that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, the all in one-line restriction will hinder readability, but you can use the short circuit boolean evaluation to add guards to your existing conditional expression, like so:

```
productName != null && productName.Url != null && productName.Url.Length > 3 
     ? "Classic": ""
```

FWIW for readability I generally format the conditional ternary operator like so:

```
var foo = prodName != null && prodName.Url != null && prodName.Url.Length > 3
  ? "Classic"
  : "";
```

Also, since C# 6 included the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators), you can reduce this slightly to:

```
var foo = productName?.Url != null && productName.Url.Length > 3 
   ? "Classic" 
   : "";
```

**Edit, re comment**

The conditional operator can be nested as well (but now you really do need indentation to preserve sanity):

```
var foo = prodName?.Url != null 
     ? prodName.Url.Length > 3
          ? "Classic"
          : ""
     : "Default Value if Prod / Prod Url is null";
```

**Nested Ternaries vs Switch based pattern matching**

Also, note that with C#8 coming out, that we'll be able to replace ternary operators with projections from the more advanced [`switch` based pattern matching](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/)

Comment: What if the else should have a value in it and if its if its null it should  get value of "" ?

Comment: One of the benefits of the conditional operator (and a subtle difference between if / then / else) is that all branches need to return a value with a compatable type (meaning the conditional needs to return something, even if it is null, again). (all of) the initial answers *also* mapped the `productName.Url null` to "". You can map it differently by nesting - updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ternary operator `?:`

```
productName.Url != null && productName.Url.Length > 3 ? "Classic" : ""
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="<%# (productName != null && productName.Url != null && productName.Url.Length > 3) ? "Classic": "" %>">..</div>
```